# Merge two RS-16 Lidars to create 3D Map

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

i would like to ask if there is a way to set and compile two rs-16 lidars, one horizontal and the other on 45 degrees. How can i merge the two different point clouds?

Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks in advance :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381517/merge-two-rs-16-lidars-to-create-3d-map/) by [ManChrys](https://answers.ros.org/users/65851/manchrys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Google cartographer will suite your description. They have specific use-case where they mount 2 LIDAR back to back, optionally supported by an IMU. [Google cartographer documention](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ManChrys](https://answers.ros.org/users/65851/manchrys/) on 2021-07-11**:
thank you for the suggestion my friend. It seems kind hard to understand exactly how to use it, as im new to ROS, but ill try it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to know the 3d transform from Lidar2 to Lidar1. Use that to transform each point in PointCloud2 into the frame used by PointCloud1. Append these new points to PointCloud1. If the robot is in motion, this simple algorithm assumes both PointClouds were captured at nearly the same time.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ManChrys](https://answers.ros.org/users/65851/manchrys/) on 2021-07-02**:
Hello and thanks for the answer.

Hmm i see!!!

Im not using robot, but i think the logic is the same. I have 2 identical rs16 3D Lidars(one horizontal and one on 45 degrees) which i put them on a custom backpack and just mapping.